# Apache Default Permissions

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, redhat

I'm pulling my hair out with Redhat at the moment...

How can I set the default user:group permissions for apache generated files and folders?

Hope this makes sense.

Tom

Comment: Sorry, not really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check /etc/passwd maybe apache user already created, in debian it's www-data, in redhat maybe something else..

Anyway this should be added to httpd.conf file. (Or any other configuration apache file in redhat (not familiar with redhat) something like apache2.conf)

```
  User www
  Group www
```

to set group and user for all public_html directory use this command

```
chown -R www:www /your_public_html
```

Comment: legend, I edited httpd.cont (found it by running: locate httpd.conf) and in there was the User and Group lines as you suggested.

Comment: Proper ownership might not be enough if the permissions are too lax.  Add chmod -R 400 to everything that is read-only content.